# Consistent alpha scale across different ggplot2 maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha

I am attempting to make a GIF of several different maps, showing how crime moves across the city at different times in the day. In order to do this, I am making several different `stat_density2d()` plots, one plot for each time interval. Here's the code:

```
data <- read.csv(".../CrimeLocationAndTime.csv", 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Get base map layer
denver = c(lon = -104.9903, lat =  39.7392)
denver_map = get_map(location = denver, zoom = 13, color = "bw")

# Get data slices
twoAMTimeSlice <- data[data$time == "2:00 AM",]
tenAMTimeSlice <- data[data$time == "10:00 AM",]

# Create density map
ggmap(denver_map, extent = "panel", maprange=FALSE) +
  stat_density2d(data = twoAMTimeSlice, 
                 aes(x = longitude, y = latitude,  fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..),
                 size = 0.1, bins = 16, geom = 'polygon') +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red", limits=c(0,2000)) + # Color scale
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.1, 0.4), guide = "legend") + # Here is the alpha scale
  geom_text(label = twoAMTimeSlice$time[1], x = -104.95, y=39.775) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5), vjust = 1),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  labs(title = "Criminal Occurrences by Time of Day")
```

So here's my problem: I need my alpha scale to be consistent across all of my maps. Currently, if I make the graphs across different times with different amounts of crime, the alpha scale does not stay consistent. This is apparent in these pictures:

[image]

Observe how the green color in this picture is very transparent and the red is more opaque. This is the correct scale that I would like to apply to all maps.

[image]

Here, observe how the green is very opaque. You can also see the legend change from the last picture. This is bad. I would like the green in this picture to be just as opaque as the last one.

I have achieved this consistency of scale for the *colors*, using the `limits` argument to `scale_fill_gradient`. However, this argument gives wonky results when applied to `scale_alpha`.

Comment: What do you mean by "wonky"? What, specifically, goes wrong? Does switching to `scale_alpha_continuous(limits=c(...,...))` instead of `scale_alpha` fix the problem?

Comment: While going through my code to answer your question, I found the solution. Originally, my "wonky" results were coming from when I was using `limits=c(0.05, 0.4)` (I thought the domain for `limits` was alpha levels, and thus [0,1]). I tried `limits=c(0, 2000)` and it worked beautifully. Thank you for asking the right questions!

Comment: For others, also see: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_steps.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution was changing the limits to

```
  limits=c(0, 2000)
```

(answered by OP in comments)